# Spring MVC 3.0: how do I define an interceptor with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am developing an app with Spring MVC (3.0).

I defined some controllers with annotations, how can I define an intereceptor with annotations too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Hopefully we'll get that in 3.1. Until then, we have to use the `HandlerInterceptor` interface.